# How to add shadow for PageTabViewStyle on SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, shadow, pagination

I use a TabView which I added a paginated view for it like this:

```
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle(indexDisplayMode: .always))
```

as you see in the bottom picture, the paginate color is like my background color & I want to add a shadow to it so it pops out a little bit more.

So how do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a background behind the dots using `indexViewStyle`:

```
.indexViewStyle(PageIndexViewStyle(backgroundDisplayMode: .always))
```